# $ global as imported 'jquery' module with Webpack

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack

I have `@types/jquery` package installed and global jQuery that is loaded separately from Webpack bundle.

This may be changed later, and I want to use `import * as $ from 'jquery'` wherever jQuery is used. I don't want real `jquery` package to be installed and bundled, only `@types/jquery' to provide TypeScript with jQuery types.

Basically I want

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

to be transpiled to

```
var $ = window.$;
```

I tried

```
  {
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    use: 'exports-loader?$=window.$'
  }
```

but it fails because there is no real `jquery` module:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '.../src'

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `externals` Webpack option:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's environment.

Conveniently, the example in link above uses jQuery for demonstration:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

**application code:**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

$('.my-element').animate(...);
```

When using this option, you can safely install `jquery` as a dependency without it ending up in your output bundle.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I really am. Used `externals` for years but then had a moment and then tried `expose` and `exports` loaders without success because they were *e* words.